# Nopcommerce ShoppingService -- I want to get the information of all the products in the shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, nopcommerce

I want to get the information of all the products and vendor in the shopping cart.Thank you so much

nopcommerce version 4.40

i want to do
[Shoppingcart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEqta.png)

i can do,
I was able to find out how many items are in the basket.

[MyShoppingcart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGsbT.png)

```
@{
var shoppingCartItems = default(IList<ShoppingCartItem>);
var shoppingCartEnabled = await _permissionService.AuthorizeAsync(StandardPermissionProvider.EnableShoppingCart);

var customer = _workContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync().Result;
if (customer.HasShoppingCartItems)
{
    var storeScope = await _storeContext.GetActiveStoreScopeConfigurationAsync();
    shoppingCartItems = await _shoppingCartService.GetShoppingCartAsync(customer, ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart, storeScope);
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you need? The count of item in cart for customer?

Comment: I want to get the information of all the products and vendor in the shopping cart.

Comment: I could only get count, I couldn't find product information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you load shoppingCartItems you have retrive all item in cart. Shopping Cart, in 4.2 version(is not your version but it's the version I use) have ProductID field. You can use this field to retrive all product information and filled into shooping cart item with a foreach cicle on shoppingCartItems.

```
var shoppingCarts = _shoppingCartService.GetShoppingCart(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, ShoppingCartType.Wishlist, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);

foreach(var sci in shoppingCarts)
{
    sci.Product = _productService.GetProductById(sci.ProductId);
}
```

Here is an example with 4.2 service version. But, 4.2 have EntityFramework and I don't need to load product info because EF load for me(sci.Product contains Product info). I don't know if 4.4 use EF or other but you can check this with a breakpoint if sci.Product is just populated.

Comment: Can you give an example with code for 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.4, if you take a look at the database or the domains, you'll see a shopping cart item has a property *ProductId*, and each product item has a property *VendorId*. By following the answer above, you'll be able to retrieve product information from the cart, and then the vendor information for each of the products in the cart.